# supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result

Tags: php, mysql, warnings, intervals, datestamp

I've got a PHP warning in my web app. I'm a bit of a noob.
I want to add a timezone offset to the 'updated' timestamp based on the 'adjusttimezone' integer in each user's profile?

This is the code:

```
$timezonequery = mysql_query('SELECT adjusttimezone FROM members WHERE member_id=' . $_SESSION["myid"]);
$timezone = (int)mysql_result('$timezonequery', 0);
$updatedquery = mysql_query('SELECT DATE_ADD(updated, INTERVAL ' . $timezone . ' HOUR) FROM projects WHERE project_id=' . $i);
```

It works, but I'm worried about this warning:

> Warning: mysql_result(): supplied
>   argument is not a valid MySQL result
>   resource in xxx.php on line 9

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Your code may be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks - please consider using prepared statements.  (And if you don't know what those terms mean, please take a moment to look them up - they're important!)

Comment: I normally use just mysql_real_escape_string(); Prepared statements look much easier! Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing $timezonequery as a string, it is expecting a mysql resource.  Remove the quotes from your mysql_result call:

```
$timezone = (int)mysql_result('$timezonequery', 0); // With quotes
$timezone = (int)mysql_result($timezonequery, 0);   // Without
```

Comment: Argh! Schoolboy error. Thanks