# store multiple row result from mySQL left join query as one variable

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am new to php and mySQL.  I have a left join query that I am using to find all the products a customer has registered.  My query works in phpmyadmin, and I can echo it in php with the following code:

```
        $custProds =  "SELECT t.prodType, s.sizes, c.color FROM registeredProducts p LEFT JOIN prodTypes t ON t.id = p.prodType LEFT JOIN prodSizes s ON  s.id = p.prodSize LEFT JOIN prodColors c ON c.id = p.prodColor WHERE p.customerID = '".$thisCust."'"; 
        $allCustProds = mysql_query($custProds);    
        while($prodRow = mysql_fetch_array($allCustProds)){
            echo $prodRow['prodType']. " - ". $prodRow['sizes']. " - ". $prodRow['color'];
            echo "<br />";
        }
```

However, I don't want to echo it for the user to see, I want to store the result in a variable for later use.  I have tried doing this instead:

```
        while($prodRow = mysql_fetch_array($allCustProds)){
            $allProds = $prodRow['prodType']. " - ". $prodRow['sizes']. " - ". $prodRow['color'];

        }
```

but that only gives me the most recent row inserted instead of all results.  Same with using `my_fetch_assoc` as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102455/access-data-stored-in-the-result-returned-from-this-query).  I have also tried this:

```
        while($prodRow = mysql_fetch_array($allCustProds)){
            $allProds = array($prodRow['prodType']. " - ". $prodRow['sizes']. " - ". $prodRow['color']);
        }
```

which echos 'Array'. I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816889/how-to-echo-an-array-in-php) and used `print_r($allProds);` which once again only gave me the last inserted row.  I have spent hours researching this and would be so grateful for any help. Thank you.

Comment: The while loop will go through all of the rows, sequentially, but you're setting $allProds to each row you get. Meaning it just gets overwritten. What you might want to do, is make $allProds an array before doing the while loop, and then push each item onto it.

Comment: Try this: `$allProds[] = ...`.

Comment: @crimson_penguin i know how to make $allProds an array but how do I push the results from the loop into it without overwriting it?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles thank you but that didn't work, still says "Array"

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out and wanted to post in case any one else has this issue. Needed to declare `$allProds` as an array, and then use `array_push` to store each instance. Then used implode to store into one variable for later use.

```
        $custProds =  "SELECT t.prodType, s.sizes, c.color FROM registeredProducts p LEFT JOIN prodTypes t ON t.id = p.prodType LEFT JOIN prodSizes s ON  s.id = p.prodSize LEFT JOIN prodColors c ON c.id = p.prodColor WHERE p.customerID = '".$thisCust."'"; 
        $allCustProds = mysql_query($custProds);
        $allProds = array();    
        while($prodRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($allCustProds)){
            array_push($allProds, $prodRow['prodType']. " - ". $prodRow['sizes']. " - ". $prodRow['color']);
        }
        $custProds = implode('<br>', $allProds);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you figured out, you needed to push the rows into an array variable. This is another form of that, using a unique ID, if you have one, in case you want to pull a specific row out later.

```
while($prodRow = mysql_fetch_array($allCustProds)){
    $allProds[$prodRow['prodID']] = array($prodRow['prodType']. " - ". $prodRow['sizes']. " - ". $prodRow['color']);
}

foreach ( $allProds as $prodID => $prodRow ) {
  echo "$prodID: $prodRow<br>";
}

// can also be accessed by:
echo $allProds[$getProdID];
```